# How to add .mdf file to create .exe setup file in C# windows application

Tags: c#, deployment

I created a C# windows application with sql server, 2008 database as backend. I would like to deploy the project along with .mdf file so as enable on client computer to create a database folder when the project is installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

Client computers wouldn't have SQL Server installed (that's what's on the server). It doesn't make sense to deploy the MDF file.

Besides, Deployment/Setup projects do not come with a step that attaches a database file to a server. I wouldn't recommend distributing a database in binary form anyway - if it's a new application I would run a setup SQL script from within my application, this means that your application will work against a variety of SQL Server versions (as MDF files are not necessarily transferrable between SQL Server versions without some massaging).